# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'addClass' - jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js:2 when dropdownlist source is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I get this message in chrome's console. the page keeps the loading sign, but nothing happens, it freezes there, the ui doesn't get displayed. And this happens when the source of a dropdownlistfor has no elements. If it has any, it works fine. Here is my code:
The ViewModelFactory:

```
SpecialOffersRep specialOffersRep = new SpecialOffersRep();
IEnumerable<SpecialOfferBO> specialOffers = specialOffersRep.GetForDropDown();

List<SelectListItem> specialOffersForDropDown = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (SpecialOfferBO sp in specialOffers)
{
    specialOffersForDropDown.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = sp.SpecialOfferName, Value = sp.SpecialOfferID.ToString() });
}
orderVm.SpecialOffers = specialOffersForDropDown;
return orderVM;
```

So I get the error when `specialOffersForDropDown` has no items.

And in the view I have this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SpecialOfferID, new { @class = "label" })
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SpecialOfferID, Model.SpecialOffers, new { data_mini = "true", id = "ddlSpecialOffer" })
     </td>
</tr>
```

I have created a test project without jquery mobile and it works fine with an empty datasource.

I have also tried `Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()` instead of `Model.SpecialOffers` but with the same error.

Comment: I managed to overcome it with a workaround, but it is not always a needed solution:  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SpecialOfferID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- choose --", new { data_mini = "true", id = "ddlSpecialOffer" })